# Why is the jQuery function showHide() undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really new at trying to use jQuery, so please forgive me for asking what is likely a simple question. Perhaps it isn't even related to jQuery, but anyway, here's the scenario. I'm trying to put in a hidden div which I only want to show up when the user hovers their mouse over the Learner's anchor tag on the page. I've started with only one anchor tag, to get it working first before implementing the rest of them. I've downloaded a jQuery library and included a reference to it, so here's some of what I've got in my page's head section:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<style type="text/css">
#navcontainer ul { list-style-type: none; }
#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }
#navcontainer ul li a
{
text-decoration:none;
padding: .2em 1em;
}
</style>
```

Next I've defined an unordered list, using the styling above to make it horizontal, and I've got a hidden div after it, which I want to show when the user moves their mouse over the first anchor in the unordered list. Here's the relevant HTML from within the body tag:

```
<body>
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onmouseout="showHide('dropdown1', false)" onmouseover="showHide('dropdown1', true); return false;">Learners</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Businesses</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="dropdown1" style="visibility:hidden;">
<ul>
<li><a href="PDFs/Learners/CloStringMap.pdf">Description A</a></li>
<li><a href="PDFs/Learners/VlaStringMap.pdf">Description B</a></li>
<li><a href="PDFs/Learners/VlnStringMap.pdf">Description C</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- other HTML code -->
</body>
```

However, when I run this from within the browser (IE11) nothing happens. Using the F12 web developers tools built into IE11 I learn that it giving an error of "showHide is undefined". Why is it doing that? The showHide() function is most certainly in the jquery-1-11.1.js file, which most certainly is in my js folder. What have I done wrong, or failed to take into account?

Comment: You're missing the most important part: `<SCRIPT>` tag where you've actually defined your `showHide(element,condition)` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery works kinda different than that. You have to make it look like this:

```
$("#dropdown1").toggle()
```

You better make a javascript file and separate the JS from the HTML:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#dropdown1">Learners</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Businesses</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="dropdown1" style="visibility:hidden;">
<ul>
<li><a href="PDFs/Learners/CloStringMap.pdf">Description A</a></li>
<li><a href="PDFs/Learners/VlaStringMap.pdf">Description B</a></li>
<li><a href="PDFs/Learners/VlnStringMap.pdf">Description C</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- other HTML code -->
</body>
```

The JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#navcontainer li a").click(function(){
        if( this.href.indexOf("#") != -1 ) {
            $( $(this).attr("href") ).toggle(); // $( "#container1" )
        }
    });
});
```

What this does is on the `navcontainer li` click, we make a handler, which does something if it contains a `#`. Then we select that element `#container1` which is in the href, also is the selector for the element which we want to show. And we toggle that element.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function as `showHide` you could use `toggle()` or `show()` or `hide()`
in you current scenario uou would couple them with $(this). or your chosen selector.

As an example of targetting a particular element with jQuery we have added the class `hover-learners` and target it with the selector below.

HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="hover-learners">Learners</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Teachers</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Businesses</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="dropdown1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="PDFs/Learners/CloStringMap.pdf">Description A</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="PDFs/Learners/VlaStringMap.pdf">Description B</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="PDFs/Learners/VlnStringMap.pdf">Description C</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Add the below javascript as a file or within `<script type="text/javascript"> code here</script>` after including your jQuery library file.

Javascript:

// wrap everything in jQuery's ready function to make sure the page has fully loaded before executing the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //select learners and apply mouseover event
    $('.hover-learners').on('mouseover', function () {
        $('#dropdown1').show();
    });

    //select learners and apply mouseout event
    $('.hover-learners').on('mouseout', function () {
        $('#dropdown1').hide();
    });

});
```

Also since the `show` and `hide` methods manipulate the `display` CSS property I have added

CSS:

```
#dropdown1 {
    display:none;
}
```

and remove the inline `style="visibility:hidden"` from the `#dropdown1`

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/J6U7d/

Comment: But there is such a function in the jquery-1.11.1.js file. Here's the beginning of the function:

    function showHide( elements, show ) {
 var display, elem, hidden,
  values = [],
  index = 0,
  length = elements.length;
 for ( ; index < length; index++ ) {
  elem = elements[ index ];

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to put a form tag into the page, and put all of my code, especially the code that uses JavaScript/jQuery within the form tag? I'm drawing at straws I know, but I'm stumped.

Comment: A form tag is certainly not necessary.  I have updated the answer.